# Не работает header() на хостинге timeweb, на другом то же самое прекрасно уже много лет работает

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает, почему
header("Location: http://events.altra-core.com/symposium/zagl.php");
нет перехода на zagl.php
На другом хостинге все работает
Ниже код, я его совсем весь обкарнала, одно поле ввода и кнопка, по нажатию на которую идет переход на zagl.php

Вот ссылка где мучаюсь, кодировка utf без bom
http://events.altra-core.com/symposium/otl.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Altracore Symposium 2019</title>
<script>        
          function sndOrderForm(){           
            document.getElementById("seen").value='true';           
            document.forms.orderform.submit();
          }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
  if ($_POST['seen']=='true') {     
        header("Location: http://events.altra-core.com/symposium/zagl.php");
        exit();    // прерываем работу скрипта, чтобы забыл о прошлом
  } else {
  ?>

<!--БЛОК MAIN-->
<main class="">
    <!--РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ-->       
    <section id="reg" class="my-50">

          <form action="" method="post" id="order" name="orderform">
              <input type="hidden" name="seen" id="seen" value="true" />               
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-row"> 

                         <div class="form-group col-md-4 m-auto py-1">
                            <input name="fname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия*" maxlength="" value="" required>
                        </div>   
                          <div class="form-group col-md-12 pt-2 text-left">                 
                            <a class="btnOr3 text-center waves-effect"  role="button" href="#" title="Регистрация" onclick="sndOrderForm(); return false;">Регистрация</a>
                        </div>                          
                    </div> 
                    </fieldset>
             </form> 
<?php
}
?>                                      
    </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.events.bcom.ru/DISIGN/2018_12_19_HPE_AMD/otl.php  вот на другом хостинге то же самое прекрасно работает

Comment: Зачем вам использовать `if ($_POST['seen']=='true') {     
        header("Location: http://events.altra-core.com/symposium/zagl.php");
        exit(); 
  } else {
  ?>`
?
Просто сделайте редирект средствами JS в sndOrderForm()

Comment: Да у меня там до header идет куча всяких обработок (записьв exel файл, отправка html письма) на Php и вот потом нужно перенаправить на zagl.php и сказать Вы зарегистрированы все ОК.

Comment: Просто странно на другом хостинге  все уже много лет работает :)
А тут вчера дали доступ к другому timeweb и все. Сайт работает, а перехода нет, хотя все обработки на php работаю. Письма приходят, в файл все записывается.
http://events.bcom.ru/DISIGN/2018_12_19_HPE_AMD/otl.php

Comment: Это может быть связано с настройками php.ini
Попробуйте обратиться в службу поддержки хостинга, думаю вам там ответят. И тогда вы будете знать наверняка в чём ошибка.

Comment: Да уже обратилась, просто ночью сделала сайт, на старом хостинге, утром сбросила на новый и на тебе. Пока они мне ответы прислали но вообще не о том.... Спасибо почитаю еще про php.ini  Если бы это все не работало на другом хостинге я бы поняла, что проблемы у меня, а так вот не пойму пока что делать...

Comment: Ответ от тех поддержки :)   Данное перенаправление является результатом работы кода. К сожалению, мы не выполняем анализ и исправление пользовательского кода, поэтому вам необходимо будет решить эту проблему самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

**https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php**

> Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать только если клиенту еще
>   не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед
>   ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.
>   Довольно часто возникает ошибка, когда при чтении кода файловыми
>   функциями, вроде include или require, в этом коде попадаются пробелы
>   или пустые строки, которые выводятся до вызова header(). Те же
>   проблемы могут возникать и при использовании PHP/HTML в одном файле.

Изучите документацию по этой функции.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо, разобралась
Hужно было блок с php 
поставить до блока html